# ADO.NET Entityframework compiled query

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework, ado.net

Hi im starting up a new project and i want to add some compiled query into my dal but i get this error i cant seem to figure out why. I couldn't find any answers in here either

> The type 'DataAccessLayer.entities' cannot be used as type parameter 'TArg0' in the generic type or method 'System.Data.Objects.CompiledQuery.Compile(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'DataAccessLayer.entities' to 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext'.

here is my code

```
public static Func<entities, string, IQueryable<user>>
            UserById = CompiledQuery.Compile((entities db, string id) => db.users.Where(u => u.id == id));
```

These is the namespaces i use

```
using System;
using System.Data.Objects;
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: Does the `entities` type you define in the lambda expression above derive from DbContext?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CompiledQuery only works with ObjectContext. Starting EF 4 or 4.1, the entities began to be derived from DbContext instead of ObjectContext.

You must be using the latest EF framework (using DbContext), and this query would have worked some time previously (ObjectContext).

Let us know your .NET & EF Versions. The newer .NET and EF versions support automatic caching of the compiled queries, so an explicit caching may become moot.